# Laravel Artisan command in queue does not remove entries from queue table in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, jobs

I am trying to queue the artisan command in the Laravel 5.8 version.
But Job entry in the database table is not deleting automatically.

I tried the following things.

**1. Directly Dispatch the artisan command as per documentation here**

[Artisan queue documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

```
Artisan::queue('set:store_permissions', [
            'app_id' => 1,
            'user_id' => 1
        ])->onConnection('database')->onQueue('upgrade_for_permissions');
```

**2. Create Job and dispatch it and in Job Call Artisan command.**

***[Dispatching]***

```
$d_t_s = new \stdClass();
$d_t_s->id = 1;
UpgradeDatabaseForPermissions::dispatch($d_t_s)->onConnection('database')->onQueue('upgrade_for_permissions');
```

***[Job calls Artisan Command]***

```
protected $user_id;
public $tries = 5;

public function __construct($d) {
    $this->user_id = $d->id;
    //
}
public function handle() {
    $user_id = $this->user_id;
    Storage::disk('local')->append('upgrade_permission.log', "Started :: user :: " . $user_id);
    $artisan = Artisan::call('set:store_permissions', [
                'app_id' => 1,
                'user_id' => $user_id
    ]);
    Storage::disk('local')->append('upgrade_permission.log', "End :: user :: " . $user_id . ' :: ');
    return true;
}
```

Both of them work perfectly the issue is Job entry is not deleting from the database automatically.

If I remove the **Artisan::call** from the Job It will automatically removed from the database.

I also tried to return true from the command itself and Job as well but none of them worked.

When I run

```
php artisan queue:work database --queue="upgrade_for_permissions"
```

It outputs as follows

```
[2019-10-03 16:22:51][1] Processing: App\Jobs\UpgradeDatabaseForPermissions                                                                                                                     
[2019-10-03 16:22:52][1] Processed:  App\Jobs\UpgradeDatabaseForPermissions
```

But does not delete the queue entry itself from the database table.
This only happens if I run artisan command in it.

**[UpgradeDatabaseForPermissions::class]**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Log;
use Artisan;
use Storage;

class UpgradeDatabaseForPermissions implements ShouldQueue {

    use Dispatchable,
        InteractsWithQueue,
        Queueable,
        SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $user_id;
    public $tries = 5;

    public function __construct($d) {
        $this->user_id = $d->id;
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle() {
        $user_id = $this->user_id;
        Storage::disk('local')->append('upgrade_permission.log', "Started :: user :: " . $user_id);
        $artisan = Artisan::call('set:store_permissions', [
                    'app_id' => 1,
                    'user_id' => $user_id
        ]);
        Storage::disk('local')->append('upgrade_permission.log', "End :: user :: " . $user_id . ' :: ');
        return true;
    }

}
```

**[Data After job completed as follows]**

- id - 1
- queue - upgrade_for_permissions
- payload - [Payload data](https://pastebin.com/zwJ5JkEN)
- attempts - 1
- reserved_at - 1570119771
- available_at - 1570119767
- created_at - 1570119767

**[upgrade_permission.log]** file

```
Started :: user :: 1
End :: user :: 1 ::
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Could you add to the question the `UpgradeDatabaseForPermissions` `class` and the data of jobs `table` after the job is processed?

Comment: Added Please check it. @RayannNayran

Comment: How are you currently dispatching the job and from where?

Comment: Currently dispatching as per 2nd option and From artisan command 
And also tried it from Controller as well.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem here calling an Artisan command from a Job but I couldn't. I think your Artisan command is buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is I am disconnecting one database connection for some other connection. 
That disconnecting causing the problems.

I connected it to the Amazon SQS queue and now everything is working fine.